# Moq in mvc throwing System.NullReferenceException

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nunit, moq

I got a customer controller as

```
     //httpget
     public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //httppost
    public ActionResult Create(Customer customer)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Customers.Add(customer);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(customer);
    }
```

I have created a unit test as

```
      [Test]
      public void Should_Return_To_Index_Page_After_Saving_A_Valid_Customer()
    {
        var mockContext = new Mock<DbContext>();
        var mockCustomer = new Mock<Customer>();
        var sut = new CustomerController(mockContext.Object);

        var result = sut.Create(mockCustomer.Object) as RedirectToRouteResult;
        Assert.That(result.RouteValues["action"], Is.EqualTo("Index"));
    }
```

But it always throws me an exception "An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred" at db.Customers.Add(customer) in Create method. Can anyone explain me where am I doing wrong?

I am a bit new to MVC nunit testing

Answer (score 0):

Your `Mock<DbContext>` is returning null for the `Customers` property.

You probably need to do something like this:

```
var mockCustomers = new Mock<IList<Customer>>(); // or whatever type it needs to be
mockContext.Setup(x => x.Customers).Returns(mockCustomers.Object);
```

Comment: It is throwing some error, the overloaded method has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to mock the `Customer` class and collection in this case. The only dependency you should be mocking in this case is the DbContext.

```
[Test]
public void Should_Return_To_Index_Page_After_Saving_A_Valid_Customer()
{
    var mockContext = new Mock<DbContext>();
    mockContext.Setup(x => x.Customers).Returns(new List<Customer>());

    var sut = new CustomerController(mockContext.Object);

    var result = sut.Create(new Customer()) as RedirectToRouteResult;
    Assert.That(result.RouteValues["action"], Is.EqualTo("Index"));
}
```